# Dynamically call content of page in another page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am trying to do something very characteristic and i am not that kinda good with PHP.

I am making some site for soccer team. And i want to have one main page called RESULTS. I will have for example 10 rounds(every round have separate page) in full season. I already make fixtures and everything depending on date.

My problem is how to call specific page, for example today is 29.10.2013 and my 3rd round has just over and i fill out all my result on my "3rd round page", and i want that this content be shown on page "RESULTS" also.

Than next week 04.11.2013 its coming my 4th round and i will also fill out everything on my "4th round page", but i just want now that all this be on "RESULTS" page because this is active round now not 3rd round.

I am guessing that i need to make template for my "RESULTS" page but i just need code, function how to call specific ID page depending on date. (29.10.2013 call page id 54; 04.11.2013 call page id 55).
I hope i explained well and hope someone is good in this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most elegant answer but should work

```
<?php 
    switch(date('d.m.Y'))
    {
        case '29.10.2013':
            $THE_PAGE_ID = 1;
        break;
        case '29.10.2013':
            $THE_PAGE_ID = 2;
        break;
        case '29.10.2013':
            $THE_PAGE_ID = 3;
        break;
        default:
            $THE_PAGE_ID = 4; // page if the date does not match
    }

    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1,
           'post_type' => 'page', 
           'include'=> $THE_PAGE_ID 
    );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <div id="page-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data of a specific page you can use "get_posts"

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Inside your page template add something like this

```
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'post_type' => 'page', 
               'include'=> $THE_PAGE_ID 
        );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php 
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</ul>
```

Or use "get_post":

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

```
<?php 
$thepost = get_post($THE_PAGE_ID, ARRAY_A);
$title = $thepost['post_title'];
echo $title;
?>
```

Hope that's what you where after.

Comment: I try to use all of this but its not that i need. Is there any forum or portal where i can get my solution for this. Ofc its not problem to pay for this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for reply, i see that you very good with this. I did like you tell me and with this i got link to page on my "RESULTS" page.

So is it possible to little bit change code that will be checking date. For example:

check date,

if date is 29.10.2013->call content(not link)of page ID=2

if date is 30.10.2013->call content of page ID=3

if date is 31.10.2013->call content of page ID=4

I would do it myself but i am not even close good with this like you. So sorry for being boring but i really need to learn this stuff.